# Merge and diff arrays of arrays to find common values

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through several database table structures and determine the common structure (ie what columns are identical). The final structure should only show common columns, so if any table has a unique column, it should not be in the final array.

This is an example of what three table structures may look like.

```
$arr1 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col2", "type"=>"int"]    
];
$arr2 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col2", "type"=>"int"]    ,
    ["name"=>"col3", "type"=>"date"]    
];
$arr3 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col3", "type"=>"int"]    
];

$arrays = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
```

Using `array_merge`, `array_diff`, `array_intersect`, or a loop, is it possible to determine which of these columns are common to all tables?

The end value should be
`[["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"]]`

Comment: What have your efforts been so far?  Can you include the code.

Comment: @NigelRen Essentially lots of crumpled up pieces of paper. Loops in loops in loops, counters for each column, pruning, merges, intersects, diffs.. Lots of tries and I've given up.

Comment: have you tried array_intersect_assoc() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom compare method with [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php):

```
$arr1 = [
    ["name" => "col1", "type" => "varchar"],
    ["name" => "col2", "type" => "int"]
];
$arr2 = [
    ["name" => "col1", "type" => "varchar"],
    ["name" => "col2", "type" => "int"],
    ["name" => "col3", "type" => "date"]
];
$arr3 = [
    ["name" => "col1", "type" => "varchar"],
    ["name" => "col3", "type" => "int"]
];

$common_columns = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, 'compareDeepValue');

print_r($common_columns);

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
    return (strcasecmp(serialize($val1), serialize($val2))) ;
}
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => col1
            [type] => varchar
        )

)
```

**Note:**

@Abracadaver made a good point this method will only work correctly when you have the array conventions in the same order.

Than you can for example use this:

```
function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
    return ($val1['name'] === $val2['name'] && $val1['type'] === $val2['type']) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Works only if they are always in the same order, try `["type"=>"varchar", "name"=>"col1"]` or more values `["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar", "default"=>"NULL"]`.

Comment: Good point, but the goal is that OP can use his custom method, which of course he can change to whatever he needs. I'll add the note, thanks.

Comment: This is working so far. Now I am just not understanding why I cannot use spread operator for the parameters.. ie `array_uintersect($arr1, ...$arrays `.. assuming I took `$arr1` out of `$arrays`

Comment: array_u* functions are not variadic because of the last positional argument. The problem is that they all take a final callback parameter (or two) after the varargs list, and that doesn't fit the rules for how variadics work.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `array_uintersect`, which does the intersection with your own function. But you should keep in mind, that the compare function does not simply returns true or false - instead you have to return `-1`, `0` or `1`.

In PHP7 you could use the spaceship operator `<=>` for the comparison.

```
$intersection = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, function($a, $b) {
    $ret = $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];
    return $ret ? $ret : $a['type'] <=> $b['type'];
});
print_r($intersection);
```

If you want to put all arrays inside the intersection, you could do this:

```
$arrays = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
$arrays[] = function($a, $b) {
    $ret = $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];
    return $ret ? $ret : $a['type'] <=> $b['type'];
};

$intersection = array_uintersect(...$arrays);
```

In older versions, you should instead use `strcasecmp`.

Comment: very nice, also love the fact you help him use the variadic argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the arrays and index by the `name` key and compute the intersection using the keys:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_column($arr1, null, 'name'),
                              array_column($arr2, null, 'name'),
                              array_column($arr3, null, 'name'));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [col1] => Array
        (
            [name] => col1
            [type] => varchar
        )
)
```

If needed, use `array_values` to get back to numeric indexes.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this does not compare the values of `type` at all

Comment: @billyonecan Correct _to determine which of these **columns** are common to all tables_

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ?

```
$arrays = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
$arrays_extended = [];

foreach($arrays as $row => $innerArray){
  foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
    array_push($arrays_extended, $value);
  }
}

var_dump(array_unique($arrays_extended));
```

> Outputs `[["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"]]`

Comment: I didn't downvote you but this throws a ton of notices because `array_unique` isn't used properly. And yeah.. this code is overall kinda broken: https://3v4l.org/1okcm

Comment: I'm not trying it on Online PHP editor and it didn't throws anything for me. But thanks for explanation.

Comment: Thats probably because your `error_reporting` / `display_errors` is not correctly configured. See [how to configure error reporting for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

1.convert elements to strings as follows:

```
 array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
      [1] =>
      string(28) "{"name":"col2","type":"int"}"
    }
    array(3) {
      [0] =>
      string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
      [1] =>
      string(28) "{"name":"col2","type":"int"}"
      [2] =>
      string(29) "{"name":"col3","type":"date"}"
    }
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
      [1] =>
      string(28) "{"name":"col3","type":"int"}"
    }
```

2.Use array intersect to find common elements

3.convert back to arrays.

```
$arr1 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col2", "type"=>"int"]    
];
$arr2 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col2", "type"=>"int"]    ,
    ["name"=>"col3", "type"=>"date"]    
];
$arr3 = [
    ["name"=>"col1", "type"=>"varchar"],
    ["name"=>"col3", "type"=>"int"]    
];

list($darr1, $darr2, $darr3) = convertArrToStr($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
/* output:
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
  [1] =>
  string(28) "{"name":"col2","type":"int"}"
}
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
  [1] =>
  string(28) "{"name":"col2","type":"int"}"
  [2] =>
  string(29) "{"name":"col3","type":"date"}"
}
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(32) "{"name":"col1","type":"varchar"}"
  [1] =>
  string(28) "{"name":"col3","type":"int"}"
}
 */
var_dump(duplicates($darr1, $darr2, $darr3));
/* output:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(4) "col1"
    'type' =>
    string(7) "varchar"
  }
}
*/    

function convertArrToStr() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as &$arg){
          foreach($arg as $k => $arr) {
                      $arg[$k] = json_encode($arr, true);
          }
    }
    return $args;
}

function duplicates($darr1, $darr2, $darr3) {
    $intersects = array_intersect($darr1, $darr2, $darr3);
    $r = [];
    foreach($intersects as $v) {
          $r[] = json_decode($v, true);    
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Hope this helps you write a more elegant solution.